# Deleting column across data frames depending on location

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply

I have a set of data frames corresponding to the sample below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, relevant_values=11:20, rubbish = runif(n = 10), 
                  important_as_well = 11:20)
df2 <- data.frame(id=1:10, something_important=11:20, not_relevant = runif(n = 10))
df3 <- data.frame(id=1:10, may_be_valid=11:20, nonsense = runif(n = 10),
                  crucial=11:20)
```

I would like to cycle through those data sets and delete the columns `rubbish`, `not_relevant` and `nonsense`. The columns are always located in the same position across the data sets, `3` as in the example above but have different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the third column using a negative index:

```
df1 <- df1[, -3]
df2 <- df2[, -3]
df3 <- df3[, -3]
```

I'd recommend against looping through and accessing these variables programmatically, and would suggest you keep them in a list if you want to do the same thing to each. However, if you do want to access them, you could use `get` and `assign`:

```
var_names <- paste0("df", 1:3)
lapply(var_names, function(n) assign(n, get(n)[, -3]))
```

Comment: I was about to say "or use a list" :)  Similar to your approach would be `l <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+")); l <- lapply(l, `[`, -3)`

Comment: Thanks, I agree that, on principle, deleting variables from all of the data frames in a loop is not the safest option, however, in this particular case the data frames are generated automatically with the unwanted variables always inserted in the `df` hence my desire to use the loop.

Comment: @Konrad Why not set up the automatically-generated data frames to be stored in a list?

Comment: Definitely could be done, each `df` is imported via `read.csv` so I could run it in a loop for import strings and then apply function to remove the column.

Comment: @Konrad yep, that's what I'd do as well. Even easier with lapply than a loop: `dfs <- lapply(file_names, read.csv, ...)` (where the ... has extra args controlling the read.csv)